# Diagonalization of infinite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

How would you diagonalize the following infinite symmetric matrix?

$$T = \left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
M \Omega^{2} + 2 \sigma  & -c_{1} & -c_{2} &  \cdots \\
-c_{1} & m_{1}w_{1}^{2} + 2 c_{1}  & 0 & \cdots \\
-c_{2} & 0 & m_{2} w_{2}^{2} + 2 c_{2}  &   \\ 
\vdots & \vdots &  &   \ddots \\ 
\end{array} \right], $$
where $\sigma = \sum_{k} c_{k} < \infty$ and $c_{k}, w_{k}, m_{k}, M, \Omega $ are constants.

Comment: "Infinite" and "matrix" don't really mix well in one sentence. It is better to use the word "operator".